# Document Scanner with specific modes

Tags: scanner

We are in search for a business document scanner with following scan options, all done over a ADF.

Simplex: front side

Duplex: front and back side

1. Simplex scan of every sheet to its own PDF.
2. Simplex scan of all sheets to one PDF.
3. Duplex scan of every sheet to its own PDF (One PDF with front and back side).
4. Duplex scan of all sheets to one PDF.

We talked with a supplier of ours and got a Brother ADS-2800W from him, but its incapable of mode nr 3.
After some research and getting back with the Brother Support, none of Brothers Scanner is apparently capable of nr 3.

Of course we also tried the usual ways (google, product comparison websites and all those "Best Scanners of >>insert year here<<"-Reviews) but none of those gave the information needed or didnt comply with at least one criteria.

Criteria:

- ADF
- A4 sheet size
- Modes listed above
- Desktop size
- WLAN / LAN
- Save to SMB Network Share
- Price of 600€ / $ top

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: You answer lies in the software not in the scanner for most of what you are looking for.  The Fujitsu IX500 Meets all your criteria but i need to test a couple of the modes you are requesting today before i post the answer.  You can see my write up on this here https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6594/document-scanner-that-respects-limited-desktop-space/6597#6597

Comment: @Jeff thats right, the biggest problem seems to be the firmware on the devices. The IX500 also looks good, I will give you some time to test the modes before I otherwise select jcam3's answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My office recently grabbed an HP ScanJet 3000 S3. It's a bit above your price range (closer to $800-900), but I've been in charge of developing our scan process and I can tell you with confidence that it does everything you listed.

We specifically got it to digitize old paper records, and it is set up at a small stand-alone desk with a computer.

- ADF = Included
- A4 sheet size = Included, also has other custom paper sizes. Smaller sheets can sometimes have trouble being grabbed by the feed mechanism, but it's functional.
- Modes listed above = All included.
- Desktop size = Fits on a pretty tiny desk with plenty of room to work. Very space efficient.
- WLAN / LAN = This feature exists but you have to buy a $40 wireless adapter that is made special just for this unit, and you can only scan to mobile devices using this method. I know don't even get me started right now, but this thing works and finding a wireless workaround solution was extremely simple since we work from a server platform. We returned the stupid $40 USB dongle.
- Save to SMB Network Share = Included.
- Price of 600€ / $ top = Nope.

It's far from a perfect solution and you usually won't find me recommending products that don't fit the user's question, but we had a particularly long and arduous experience trying to find something that would fit our needs. I see similar conditions in your post. We had to make a few compromises, but at the end of the day we needed something and this little headache of a scanner made our project possible. Perhaps it can do the same for you.

I can definitely tell you that unless you're looking for something used, duplex auto-document feed scanners that can handle even a 50 page count stack at a time don't exist for under $600. Well, they may exist, but there wasn't anything I found that was suitable and trustworthy enough for business use.

Comment: That sounds great, also i looked around and the price is about 500€ in some shops so it would also meet that criteria.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Like I said, it's not perfect but it'll get the job done without forcing you to purchase a massive tower printer/copier. Alternatively, if you already have one of those (we do), it will get the job done without preventing that tower printer from supporting the rest of the office since that's what you bought it for. Workflow was really our major concern at the end of the day after all.